# Laravel json contain

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel 7. I have a column in my db which contain json data

```
 if(!empty($where['shopify->referring_site'])){
            $orders_query->orwhere(function($query) use($where) {
                if(!empty($where['shopify->referring_site'])){
                    $all_val = explode(",",$where['shopify->referring_site']);
                    foreach($all_val as $key_num=>$val){
                        $query->orwhereJsonContains('shopify->referring_site','%https://organicboutique.org/products%');
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

I want to get data using "LIKE" operator but its not working for me. In the above code I want to get the "shopify->referring_site" all value who contains "organicboutique"

I tired this one as well

```
$query->orwhereJsonContains('shopify->referring_site','like','%https://organicboutique.org/products%');
```

Comment: use like as the second params like: $query->orwhereJsonContains('shopify->referring_site','like','%https://organicboutique.org/products%');

Comment: Its not working like you suggest

Answer (score 0):

use this syntax

```
$query->orwhere('shopify->referring_site','like','%'.$val.'%');
```